# Laravel paginator not working - custom paginator construction

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to construct a paginator with the following code:

```
// Convert to array for paginator
$events=$events->toArray();

// Pagination
$events = Paginator::make($events, count($events), $variables->eventsPerPage);

return $events;
```

But all this does is add pagination variables to the $events object - it doesn't actually limit the number of results returned:

```
{"total":10,"per_page":1,"current_page":1,"last_page":10,"from":1,"to":1,
    "data":[
        // 10 objects returned here even though per_page is 1
    ]
}
```

NB: Before pagination code, `$events` object consists of 10 objects.

Comment: Please update your question to describe with more detail what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When constructing a Pagination instance manually, no data manipulation is done. You're simply generating a `Paginator` class to assist you with displaying the information you're presenting to it.

You'll need to manipulate your `$events` array/collection manually in order to reduce it to the appropriate chunk of data.